# How to run ffmpeg in a scheduled batch file with a file exclusion list?

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, schedule

I have the following batch file created to run as a schedule task. It auto encodes the audio to AAC in my main media folder. Everything is working, but now I need to do 2 more things:

1. Delete the original upon completion.
2. Set it so that the next time it runs, it does not try to convert the already converted files.

Is that possible? How would that look? Is there a way to "disregard" file names with `CONVERTED` in them?

```
for /r "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\TEST" %%a in ("*.mkv") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vcodec copy -acodec aac -ac 2 -ab 256K %%~dpnaCONVERTED.mkv
```

Comment: If you delete the original how is it going to convert a file that is already converted? If you want to delete the file then put in a delete command after the conversion.

Comment: Looking at your code tells me the source and destination are different. If you delete it from the source, how is it going to get converted again.

Comment: To ignore files that may have been converted you can use the IF command withe the EXIST option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done with following batch file:

```
@echo off
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%UserProfile%\Desktop\TEST\*.mkv" /A-D-H /B /S 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /E /I /L /V /C:CONVERTED.mkv 2^>nul') do (
    ffmpeg.exe -i "%%I" -vcodec copy -acodec aac -ac 2 -ab 256K "%%~dpnICONVERTED.mkv"
    if not errorlevel 1 del "%%I"
)
```

The command **FOR** executes in a separate command process started with `cmd.exe /C` in background (= not visible) the command line:

```
dir "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\TEST\*.mkv" /A-D-H /B /S 2>nul | C:\Windows\System32\findstr.exe /E /I /L /V /C:CONVERTED.mkv 2>nul
```

So the command process in background with no console window is first running command **DIR** which outputs

- all non hidden files because of `/A-D-H` (attribute not directory and not hidden)
- matching the wildcard pattern `*.mkv`
- in bare format because of `/B` which means file name only
- in specified directory and all its subdirectories because of `/S`
- with full path also because of `/S`
- to handle **STDOUT**.

**DIR** outputs an error message if it can't find any *.mkv file. This error message written to handle **STDERR** is suppressed by redirecting it to device **NUL** with `2>nul`.

The file names with full path output by **DIR** line by line to handle **STDOUT** are redirected with `|` to handle **STDIN** of next command **FINDSTR**.

**FINDSTR** searches in the list of file names for

- comparison string `CONVERTED.mkv`
- at end of a line because of `/E`
- case-insensitive because of `/I`
- and literally because of `/L`
- and outputs the inverted result because of `/V`.

That means **FINDSTR** outputs the lines **not** ending with case-insensitive, literally interpreted comparison string `CONVERTED.mkv` to ignore the *.mkv file converted already in a previous execution of the batch file.

It is possible that **FINDSTR** can't find any line matching the search criteria and therefore outputs an error message to handle **STDERR** which is suppressed by redirecting it with `2>nul` to device **NUL**.

The command **FOR** captures the output written to handle **STDOUT** of the background command process which is the output of **DIR** filtered with **FINDSTR** and then processes this output line by line.

Empty lines are ignored by **FOR**. But that does not matter here as the list of file names with full path does not contain empty lines.

Lines starting with a semicolon would be also ignored by **FOR**, but this behavior is modified with `eol=|` to ignore just lines starting with a vertical bar. A vertical bar is impossible here as no directory or file can contain a vertical bar in name. Well, it is also practically impossible that a file name with full path starts with a semicolon. So `eol=|` would not be really needed here.

**FOR** with parameter `/F` splits by default a line up into substrings using space and horizontal tab as string delimiters and assign only the first space/tab delimited string to specified loop variable `I`. This split behavior is not wanted here as needed in body command block of **FOR** is always the full qualified name of an MKV file even on path or file name contains a space character. For that reason `delims=` is specified to define an empty list of delimiters which disables splitting up the lines into substrings.

`ffmpeg.exe` is executed which I don't have installed and so I can only assume that it exits with `0` on success and with any value greater `0` on an error.

The exit code of an executed application or command is assigned by Windows command interpreter to environment variable `ERRORLEVEL`.

The **IF** condition checks if `ffmpeg.exe` exited **not** with a value **greater or equal** `1`, i.e. with `0` (or a negative value) for success. In this case the input file is deleted as wanted to prevent a conversion of same file once again on next run of this batch file.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul` and `|`. The redirection operators `>` and `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded command line with using a separate command process started in background.